# React app not not display db details though it is showing in console log

Tags: create-react-app

This is Home page

import React, { useEffect,useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Home(){

```
const [hotels,setHotels]=useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  loadHotels();
},[]);

 const loadHotels =async() =>{
    const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/hotels");
    setHotels(result.data);
 }
return (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="py-4">
      <table className="table table-striped table-bordered shadow table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {hotels.map((hotel, index) => (
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" key={index}>{index+1}</th>
              <td>{hotel.name}</td>
              <td>{hotel.location}</td>
              <td>{hotel.website}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

}

Data is not showing on React after npm start